# Add a column with header title in handsontable js vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, handsontable

I'm trying to dynamically add a column in HandsonTable on button click.

I can add a column, but I cannot seem to change the column header.

Here is a code snippet

```
const settings = {
    ...
    manualColumnResize: true,
    colHeaders: ['Name', 'Percent'],

}

function click() {

    const table = studentsTableRef.value.hotInstance

    table.suspendRender();
    table.alter('insert_col_end',3);
    table.updateSettings({
        colHeaders: ['Name', 'Percent', "Test"],
    })

    table.resumeRender();
}


...

data = [ // data is a ref
    [null, null],
    [null, null]
]

<HotTable ref="tableRef" :data="data" :settings="settings"></HotTable>
```

It successfully adds a new column, but just defaults to the default "C". The new column header is not Test.

I'm clearly missing something, but I cannot find anything in the docs to set a header data.

Comment: Hi. This seems like a bug. I tested it with the Angular wrapper, and it works the same. We can enable and disable many options and plugins but not the `colHeaders`. I will report it to the team.  If you would like to get notifications about the issue status please contact support@handsontable.com

Comment: I checked that again, and it will work if you wrap the `updateSettings()` in `setTimeout()` (you do not need to add any time for the delay.